# Lamp flickers if dimmed up to an extent

Tags: microcontroller, ac, triac, dimming, dimmer

I used circuit shown in this instructable to make an AC dimmer but everything goes fine if not dimmed much but then it starts flickering because of voltage fluctuation.

http://www.instructables.com/id/Arduino-controlled-light-dimmer-The-circuit/?ALLSTEPS

EDIT - embedding circuit

[image]

Comment: Have you tried using the comment section on the page you linked? This would appear the sensible 1st approach. Also, what precisely is your load?

Answer (score 1):

A few things to try- and take extreme care as the author suggests- no shortcuts.

- short out the indicator LED in case the MOC is not getting enough drive. I don't think this us your problem, since your flicker varies with the dimming, but as he mentions it it's worth a try.
- make sure your load is 'simple' like an incandescent lamp. Get it working first with that before trying CCFLs or LED lamps. If you're using an incandescent bulb, try doubling the wattage of the load and see if it improves.
- The 1K series resistor is very high-- you could try reducing that to 1/2 or 1/4 and see if it improves.

(I would have put the load on MT2 rather than MT1 to minimize the dv/dt at the opto coupler, but I doubt that's related)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using an incandescent bulb, flickering can be caused by only triggering the triac on the one half cycle...might need to check your code.

Answer (score 0):

I struggled same.
Please check your interrupt it should be at rising edge not at falling.
1k ohm and 220 ohm are perfect do not change them.
you can swap mt1 and mt2 if triac is not firing at all.